# Postman Error "status": 500, "error": "Internal Server Error", "message": "Index: 1, Size: 1"}

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am getting `IndexOutOfBoundsException` when loop is running in second time
Postman error

**Code**

```
public Object example() {
    String userId = getLoggedInUserId();
    User u = userDao.getUserById(userId);
    List<String> categoryIds = u.getCategoryAccess();
    List<Category> categoryList = categoryDao.getUserCategoriesById(categoryIds);
    List<SubCategory> subCategoryList = categoryDao.getUserSubCategoriesById(categoryIds);

    List<String> subCategoriesIds = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i =0;i<subCategoryList.size();i++)
    {
        subCategoriesIds.add(subCategoryList.get(i).getId());
    }
    List<Items> itemsList = categoryDao.getUserItemsBySubCategoryIds(subCategoriesIds);

    List<Category> FirstLoop = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int j = 0;j<categoryList.size();j++)
    {
        FirstLoop.add(categoryList.get(j));

        List<SubCategory> SecondLoop = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int k=0;k<subCategoryList.size();k++)
        {
            if(categoryList.get(j).getId().equals(subCategoryList.get(k).getCategoryId()))
            {
                SecondLoop.add(subCategoryList.get(k));
                FirstLoop.get(j).setSubCategory(SecondLoop);
            }

            List<Items> ThirdLoop = new ArrayList<>();

            for(int l =0;l<itemsList.size();l++)
            {
                if(subCategoryList.get(k).getId().equals(itemsList.get(l).getSubCategoryId()))
                {
                    ThirdLoop.add(itemsList.get(l));
                    SecondLoop.get(k).setItems(ThirdLoop);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return FirstLoop;
}
```

**IndexOutOfBoundsException**

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
    at com.website.website.service.CartService.example(CartService.java:233) ~[classes!/:0.1.2]
    at com.website.website.controller.CartController.example(CartController.java:102) ~[classes!/:0.1.2]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
```

**Postman error**

```
{
    "timestamp": "2020-12-25T10:55:00.602+0000",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "Index: 1, Size: 1",
    "path": "/api/Cart/example"
}
```

Comment: Step through your code with a debugger and you'll see what's wrong. What is line 233?

Comment: SecondLoop.get(k).setItems(ThirdLoop); line 233

Comment: So at that point, is it guaranteed that you've added k items to SecondLoop?

Comment: yes i have added

Comment: So every iteration of the loop over k, you add an item to SecondLoop?

Comment: yes i am adding items to SecondLoop

Comment: Which line does that happen in? Does that line get executed on every iteration of the loop over k?

Comment: SecondLoop.get(k).setItems(ThirdLoop); in this line i am adding . only one loop is iterating and the next iteration its showing error

Comment: That line doesn't add any items to SecondLoop.

Comment: You need to either step through your code with a debugger, or add a number of print statements, so that you can understand what your program is doing.